# How to prevent ManagementObjectNotFoundException from printing

Tags: powershell, error-handling, try-catch

I'm trying to test out a script that creates exchange mailboxes for existing users.  At the end I want to have a little piece that tests and informs the user whether or not it was successful.  What I have is below.

```
$mail = Get-Mailbox user@domain.com

$checkmail = @($mail).count

if($checkmail -eq 0)
{
write-host "Does not exist"
}
else
{
write-host "exists"
}
```

This actually works just fine, but when the object doesn't exist, it also spits out a huge Powershell error to boot.  I just don't want that part to be there.  I've tried a try/catch block on the whole thing, and it for some reason just ignored it.  The error is as follows:

```
Get-Mailbox : The operation could not be performed because object 'user@domain.com' could not
be found on the domain controller 'domainnamehere'
+ $mail = Get-Mailbox user@domain.com
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo            : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Mailbox], ManagementObjectNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorID   : 3AAE54AC,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.Getmailbox
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried for the `try` block? You might need to set the `-ErrorAction` of `Get-Mailbox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do is set the `-ErrorAction` for `Get-Mailbox`

```
$mailbox = Get-Mailbox asdf@ba.net -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

The error for that command will be surpressed from the console ( but still occur ). You will have to check the value of `$mailbox` in case it is empty with a simple `If`.

```
If($mailbox){
    Write-Host "Good mailbox"
} Else {
    Write-Host "Bad mailbox"
}
```

The try block might not have worked if the error was non-terminating. If you have a try block setting `-ErrorAction Stop` might have made that work as well.